# replacing local css with CDN url in usemin

Tags: css, cdn, grunt-usemin

I am using grunt build to copy files from production to build. While working I am using local bootstrap css, however in build I need CDN url to be replaced for bootstrap.

```
<!--build:css http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- endbuild-->
```

First of all is this possible? Grunt build is giving error for http path while using usemin.

Thanks.

Comment: What is preventing you using the CDN locally?

If you need to replace the link in your index.html, then you can use https://github.com/tunderdomb/rebase to rewrite that part of your content, or perhaps something like `cdnify` to attempt to convert your local references to CDN paths as part of your build.

Now that `grunt` isn't so well supported now - perhaps `gulp` would provide you with better tooling to achieve this?

Comment: @Squiggle thanks for your reply. I am using local bootstrap file just in case there is connectivity issue, it should not hamper production. I will check the URL you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Could you update your question to address these points? and provide more details about what you've already tried, including code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Got temporary solution to this.

My grunt build was perfect except http:// url for bootstrap.  So i used --force (grunt build --force) command to build my project.

This gave me warning but build the project as per my requirements and CDN url for bootstrap.